# regexp to check if input is only whole numbers (int) , and to check if another is only numbers with 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know what a regex would look like for:

1. only whole numbers
2. only numbers with less than or equal to two decimal places (23, 23.3, 23.43)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Only whole numbers:

```
/^\d+$/
         # explanation
\d       match a digit
 +       one or more times
```

Numbers with at most 2 decimal places:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/

         # explanation
 \d       match a digit...
 +        one or more times
  (        begin group...
   ?:      but do not capture anything
   \.      match literal dot
   \d      match a digit...
   {1,2}   one or two times
  )        end group
 ?        make the entire group optional
```

Notes:

- The slashes denote start and end of pattern
- `^` and `$` are start and end of string anchors. Without these, it will look for matches anywhere in the string. So `/\d+/` matches `'398501'`, but it also matches `'abc123'`. The anchors ensures the *entire* string matches the given pattern.
- If you want to allow negative numbers, add a `-?` before the first `\d`. Again, `?` denotes "zero or one time."

---

#### Usage example:

```
var rx = new RegExp(/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/);
console.log(rx.test('abc'));      // false
console.log(rx.test('309'));      // true
console.log(rx.test('30.9'));     // true
console.log(rx.test('30.85'));    // true
console.log(rx.test('30.8573'));  // false
```

Comment: Best explanation of this I've ever seen.

Answer (score 6):

I. `[1-9][0-9]*` if the number should be greater than zero (any series of digits starting with a nonzero digit). if it should be zero or more: `(0|[1-9][0-9]*)` (zero or a nonzero number). If it can be negative: `(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)` (zero or a nonzero number that can have a minus before it.)

II. a regex like I. followed by: `(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` that means, optionally a dot followed by one or two digits.

Comment: the most important thing is figuring out WHY these regexes work! regexes use a different logic than program flow.

Answer (score 4):

Whole numbers only

```
/\d+/
```

One or two decimal places:

```
/\d(\.\d{1,2})?/
```

Comment: Your second one doesn't match whole numbers

Comment: True - originally thought that was the intention, didn't read the question carefully enough. Fixed